# How to get the cookie value from a Rest Webservice

Tags: java, cookies, jax-rs

Which annotation from Jax-RS api was used to retrieve the cookie value?

I tried with the below code

```
 public String getCookieValue(@Context HttpHeaders headers){
   headers.getCookies()  

 }
```

above code snippet gives a Map. how to retrieve a specific cookie value from it..!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to javadoc, `headers.getCookies()` call retrieves you "a read-only map of cookie name (String) to Cookie".

```
Map<String, Cookie> cookies = hh.getCookies();
Cookie myCookie = cookies.get("your cookie name");
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir.. I stored a cookie with name 'guid' and value 123456.Now I want to get the cookie value 123456 by using name guid but as per ur code it should return a string but returning a Cookie object....

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [@CookieParam](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/CookieParam.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned to return `String` and you are returning a `map` object, it must not be working.

Try this:

```
 public String getCookieValue(@Context HttpHeaders headers){
   return headers.getCookies().toString;  
 }
```